# How to create and electron project that runs a angular project in a window (desktop application)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron, desktop-application

I am currently building an electron/angular application. My block is that I do not know how to nest my electron app and my angular app together. at the moment, my angular application has no electron in the project itself. What I know how to do is create an entirely seperate electron application, and using

```
mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:4200");
```

im able to load the angular app inside my electron apps window.

ultimately, I need these two applications to be one single application. I have searched online all day for how to create an electron application with angular and typescript but I've ran across mostly outdated information or information that does not seem to work for me.

Im assuming what must happen is a nesting of the two projects.

the reason I need to use electron is because this application will need access to the users local file system to extract paths and file/folder names (another issue that seems difficult to find examples of).

Does anyone know of a resource I could use to help me understand how to create an electron application that uses typescript and angular? and if anyone can shed some light on how to access a computers local files/folders using electron that would be helpful as well. I understand that it is most likely a service and therefore it seems like i might need to first get the electron and angular application into a single application before im able to create a service that utilizes electrons ability to access local files systems.

Comment: You could do it with the help of a package `npm install python-shell`

Comment: if i were to run npm install python-shell in the directory of the extension, what would it do and how would it help me?

Comment: I intended for you to use this package. You need to read the documentation provided, there are ready-made code snippets also available that you need to make use of to achieve the desired results.

Comment: just to be clear, is this the documentation you are referring to? https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell